# Three Envelopes Problem

Tags: probability, games

In a game we have 3 envelopes, *A*, *B*, *C*, with a random number (from 1 to 100) sealed inside each. Nobody knows what number is inside. We win the game if we find the highest number, using only one of 2 ways (options):

**Option#1;** we can select 2 envelopes and open one of them, if the number inside it's lower than the other selected we lose the game, if instead, it's higher we can stay with that number and hope that it is higher than the third envelope; if it is not higher when opened the last envelope, we lose the game.

**Option#2;** we can select 1 envelope and find out if it is higher than the rest, and if it is not we lose the game.

**Probability#1;** we have 1/2 chance that our number is higher than the other number inside the envelope we have selected at the beginning, and then we'll have 1/3 chance that our number is higher than the third as well, so the probability to find the highest number this way should be: (1/2)(1/3)=1/6 correct? because we need to find first the probability to pick the highest from two and then the highest from three (even if we already know that at least one is not higher than ours).

**Probability#2;** we have 1/3 chance that the number inside the envelope we choose is higher than the rest.

It sounds strange to have less probability to find the highest number with option#1 than option#2, but maybe my calculations are wrong, what do you think?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how the options are really any different. Either way, you are choosing one envelope without knowing the contents of the other two envelopes, and you can't change your choice either way. For option #1, can you switch to the third envelope if the envelop you initially selected was the higher of the two envelopes picked? I was expecting some variation of the Monty Hall problem here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calculating **Probability#1**, you say:

> we'll have 1/3 chance that our number is higher than the third as well

This is not true since you proceed to this step only when your number is higher than a number in other envelope selected at the begining. So in this step you compare *maximum* from envelopes selected at the begining with the last envelope. So you have 2/3 chance that your number is higher than the last one.

Final probability is then (1/2)*(2/3) = 1/3